# Convex polygons partitioned into concave quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

I found the following problem:

> Is it possible to partition every convex polygon into a finite number concave quadrilaterals?

The answer seems negative, because heuristically if we remove a concave quadrilateral the new polygon is still convex, and after a finite number of steps we arrive at a concave quadrilateral in end, and therefore a contradiction.

The problem is that it is possible to have some weird configurations, and removing a any quadrilateral from the partition may make the resulting polygon non-convex.

What is the answer to the question, and what is the proof?

Moreover, is there a more general result like:

> It is impossible to partition a convex set into a finite number of regular,  connected non-convex sets? (Answer: NO)
>
> What happens if we remove the finiteness assumption?

Comment: what do you mean by "regular"?  It's easy to partition a square into two non-convex pentagons.

Comment: Something which looks nice enough, for example piecewise $C^1$.

Comment: Is it possible to construct any convex set at all from a finite number of non-overlapping concave quadrilaterals? Is it even possible to construct a bounded convex set as an infinite union of non-overlapping concave quadrilaterals? Good question!

Comment: @TonyK: for the infinite case, see my answer.

Comment: @Robert: That's why I said "bounded"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copy'n'paste the solution from problem 5 at http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=543&lmm=0 ---

The answer is no. Assume that, on the contrary it is possible to partition a polygon $P$ into non-convex quadrilaterals. Let $n$ be the number of quadrilaterals. Denote by $S$ the total sum of all internal angles of all the quadrilaterals. Since the sum of internal angles of each quadrilateral is $360^\circ$ we have $S=360^\circ n$. However, each of the nonconvex angles has to be in the interior of $P$, hence the sum of angles around the vertex of that angle has to be $360^\circ$. This immediately gives $360^\circ n$ as the sum of angles around such vertices. Since those are not the only vertices (at least the vertices of $P$ will contribute to the sum $S$), we have that $S\gt360^\circ n$ and this is a contradiction.

Comment: So simple!${}$${}$

Comment: I also found this solution last night. :)

Answer (score 4):

Partitioning a square into two non-convex pentagons:

[image]

EDIT: Partitioning the plane into concave quadrilaterals:

[image]

EDIT: Partitioning a triangle into infinitely many concave quadrilaterals.

[image]

Comment: That solves the last part :)

Comment: If I could upvote twice I would :) Thank you.